# C++: int array[][N] vs int array[N][N]

Tags: c++, arrays

Here two lines of array defenition (static version):

```
int A[N][N] = {};
```

and

```
int A[][N] = {};
```

Why are both lines working?
Pros and cons (if any).
Newbie in C++ syntax, but a complex and detailed explanation is welcome (if there is one)

Comment: You second block of code should not compile and does not compile here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d3efe7430654a57

Comment: If you don't specify array dimension, it will be deduced from the initializer. But there are no 0-size arrays in C++.

Comment: This reads like a homework question, asked in a chapter that talks about array declarations, is it? If not, then in which context did this question arise?

Comment: GCC, Clang and ICC without specifying the `-pedantic-errors` (or `-pedantic` for some reason?) flag still compile this, although it is not valid standard C++. Make a habit of using that compiler flag to avoid being surprised that your code won't work on other compilers.

Comment: But it still compiles by c++ command in linux and idk why. Also valid syntax for passing args to functions

Comment: @FLYFOX2058 The part that is ill-formed is not `int A[][N]` as such, but specifically that the size for the first empty bracket will be deduced to `0` in `int A[][N] = {};` (because the braces are empty). An array in standard C++ may not have size `0`. As I mentioned above, the common compilers on linux (especially GCC) do still allow it by default as a compiler extension. Add the `-pedantic-errors` flag to the invocation of `c++` to have it behave more standard-compliant.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> int A[][N] = {};
> ```

This is ill-formed, because array variables may not be empty in C++.

This would be well-formed:

```
int A[][N] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
}; // int[2][N]
```

> Pros and cons (if any).

The pro of not specifying the size of the array is that the size of the array and the number of initialisers cannot become mismatched due to refactoring.

The pro of specifying the size of the array is that you don't have to provide an initialiser for all elements.

Comment: Understand, but why it is working well for example in passing args to functions 
 (example: void func(int arr[][N]))

Comment: @FLYFOX2058 Function parameters are never arrays. When you declare a function parameter as an array, it will be adjusted to be a pointer to such array.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start simpler. 1D arrays:

```
int x[3] = {1,2,3};  // array with 3 elements 
int x[] = {1,2,3};   // size 3 can be infered from the initializer
int x[3] = {};       // elements are zero initialized
int x[3] = {1};      // first element is 1, the others are zero initialized
```

For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization. And the same extends to 2-d arrays.

However, `int x[] = {};` is not valid C++, because there are no 0-sized arrays and same for `int A[][N] = {};`. Its a compiler error. If it is not a compiler error then it may come as a compiler extension and you need to tweak compiler flags to compile in standard compliant mode.

Comment: But it compiles with no error in linux by command c++. May be i'm wrong?
And still its valid syntax for passing arguments to function (example: void func(int arr[][N]))

Comment: @FLYFOX2058 " If it is not a compiler error then it may come as a compiler extension and you need to tweak compiler flags to compile in standard compliant mode." which compiler are you using? WIth gcc try `-pedantic`. Declaring an array is not the same as declaring a function argument

Comment: @FLYFOX2058 note that also `int arr[][N] = {{1,2},{3,4}};` is fine. Its the 0-size infered from the initializer that is the issue